# Spring Boot how execute stored procedure multiple times?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to execute a procedure multiple times with the requestbody. For now, i am using for loop to do that, but it is not a good way. For example, when the one request is failed, catching that request is a problem. [See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4BeE.png) for the example usage.

Implementation of stored procedure with for-loop;

```
**Controller**
public void runSP(
   @RequestBody List<IdNoteModel> idNotes
){
   getService().runSP(idNotes);
}
```

```
**Service**
public void runSP(List<IdNoteModel> idNotes){
   for (IdNoteModel idNote : idNotes){
      getRepository().runSP(idNote);
   }
}
```

```
**Repository**
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "EXECUTE PROCEDURE SP_RUN_ID_NOTE(:id, :note)")
void runSP(Long id, String note);
```

Is there a better way to run stored procedures multiple times? or do you have an idea to catch the failed requests?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one stored procedure in which you can use the cursor to execute the procedure (`SP_RUN_ID_NOTE`) multiple times. In that stored procedure, you can also use rollback for something to fail. In your above case, you can store request body input in the table and then call procedure while taking input row from that table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@Retryable** for this purpose and also you can catch exceptions and log requests with **@Recover**